# How can I know, what local port is used by Stream?

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, node.js

Is it possible to specify explicitly local port that should be used by `net.Stream`, or to find out what local port is used for connection?

According to the documentation, local port cannot be specified:

```
stream.connect(port, host='127.0.0.1')
```

Comment: you want to connect to a server, or listen on a port?

Comment: I'm connecting to a server, and trying to find out, to which local port client socket is bound

Comment: The real question is: what do you want to achieve? The remote party is in a better position to determine your port number, as it sees the IP address/port number after all the modifications that intermediate NATs and proxies may have made.

Comment: Local port specified explicitly is required by Scala Remote Actors communication protocol - that's what I need it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stream.connect(port, host='127.0.0.1')
```

listed the specified address with specified port.

If you want to open socket, you have to use `net.createConnection(port, host='127.0.0.1')`, `http.createServer` or smth like that...
In Linux to show all listened sockets, type `netstat -an`

Comment: I want to open a client socket (not a **server socket**, which reacts to outgoing connections). Every client socket is bound to a local port, which is used to receive response from the server socket. I'm trying to figure out in runtime, which port is used. With `netstat -tlnp` it's possible to figure out, which port is used by the client socket (by process ID), but I want to have something less cumbersome.

Comment: Looks like it's impossible to find out what local port is used via API, so I'll have to use `netstat -tlnp` to get it by the process ID.

Comment: You can use socket.localPort.

Answer (score 0):

According to the node.js documentation (http://nodejs.org/api.html) there is no method or variable exposed that provides the information you are looking for.  I would suggest either submitting a patch (http://nodejs.org/#contributing) or making a request through a mailing list (http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

If you control the server you could ask it to tell you.  Not pretty, but not unlike the hoops you have to jump through when trying to negotiate peer-to-peer connections from behind NAT.